# AttributeGraph Detected while Showing HTML Text in SWIFTUI

Tags: html, swift, swiftui

I tried the following code and getting the Warning :

```
=== AttributeGraph: cycle detected through attribute 682680 ===
```

extension :

```
extension Data {
    var html2AttributedString: NSAttributedString? {
        do {
            return try NSAttributedString(data: self, options: [.documentType: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html, .characterEncoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue], documentAttributes: nil)
        } catch {
            print("error:", error)
            return  nil
        }
    }
    var html2String: String { html2AttributedString?.string ?? "" }
}

extension StringProtocol {
    var html2AttributedString: NSAttributedString? {
        Data(utf8).html2AttributedString
    }
    var html2String: String {
        self.html2AttributedString?.string ?? ""
    }
}
```

swiftui :

```
description = "<p class=\"uitk-flex-item uitk-flex-basis-full_wi......."
Text(description.html2String)
```

I am not understanding why the warning is coming because after the warning my codes behaviour is very strange. Have someone any Idae?

Comment: You need to [edit] your question to include all relevant code in the form of a [mcve] in order to make the question on-topic.

Comment: Where is SwiftUI issue here? It is just working with swift and optional!

Comment: I am using it in swiftui and actually its working sometimes, but sometimes it get the "AttributeGraph" warning...

Comment: @DávidPásztor this is the "MRE" cause I just want to use the html string into the Swiftui Text

Comment: @osman this is not a MRE. There isn’t any SwiftUI code included. It does not reproduce the issue.